# Win98se (VMWARE Session) login to Win2008 Server Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, vmware-workstation

I have a WinXP workstation w/ a vmware 98se session. I need to log in to a Win 2k8 standard server. I ran the DSclient pkge that is required and made the Regedit changes but no luck. Can anyone help regarding this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the gear here presently to try this, but it looks like there's some incompatibiltiy in W2K8's SMB server beyond the traditional "disabled digital signatures" that we've had to do with W2K3 for a number of years now.

On the Windows 98SE client computer, I'm seeing that the "DSClient" package and possible Internet Explorer 6, SP1 need to be installed.

On the Windows Server 2008 machine to which you will be "mapping" a "drive" (or otherwise connecting with SMB), you'll need to configure the security option settings below as follows:

- Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (if server agrees): Enabled
- Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (always): Disabled

You'll also need to add the following registry values to that server computer:

Under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MAHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
```

- Value name "EnableRaw", type REG_DWORD, value 0
- Value name "SMB2", type REG_DWORD, value 0

Be aware that htis disables the SMB 2.0 protocol on the server computer and will slow down access from Windows Vista and newer clients and servers.

The "LMcompatibilitylevel" setting on the server computer may need to be set to "2", or you may need to get NTLMv2 running on the Win98SE clients. To change the "LMcompatibiltylevel" setting on the server computer, modify the "Network security: LAN Manager authentication level" security option. I believe that the "Send NTLM response only" is the setting you're looking for.

It's theoretically possible that you may be able to enable NTLMv2 authentication on your Win98SE clients per the following procedure: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/239869

The 98SE DSClient package is a nasty thing. There are updates and hotfixes that are not generally available that can fix known problems with it, but I think Microsoft has made it purposefully hard to get ahold of to encourage people to drop Win98SE.

Answer (score 1):

I am not having any luck with this or any other information regarding this subject.

My one and only question is "Has it actually been done before?" The win98 box seems to see the Server due to the error messages I've been getting. I can also ping it...(that doesn't really mean much) but I cannot get a full login to happen.

Microsoft network server: Digitally sign communications (always): Disabled 
seems to be disabled. My Enable/Disable are greyed out.

Also , I am getting an error stating that my password or user name is incorrect but, that is not the case. Anymore ideas?

One thing that I am thinking about is that the version of 2k8 I'm using is beta? Wonder if that makes a differeence?